# Nodejs Mysql gives error, when i fetch two fields using OR

Tags: mysql, node.js

Actually i am trying to make a login API using nodejs and mysql.

When i try to make query like

```
"SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE (`email` = '9592443536' || `mobile` = '9592443536') 
AND `password` = '25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b'",
```

above query working perfect in phpMyAdmin but not working using nodejs.

My code is below.

```
let query = [email,email,password];

    //let q = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`email` = ' + email + ' || `mobile` = ' + email + ') AND `password` =' + password;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (`email` = ? || `mobile` = ?) AND `password` = ?", query ,function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        if(results.length == '0'){
            res.status(400).send({'result':'email and password does not matched'});
        }
    });
```

GOT ERROR =

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresp           onds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/html/office/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/pro           tocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)

When i console the executed query i got the same as above

```
 "SELECT * 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE (`email` = '9592443536' || `mobile` = '9592443536') 
    AND `password` = '25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b'",
```

DATABASE screenshot - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZmRI.png)

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really have `**` in the query, or was that just an attempt at highlighting

Comment: I am also pretty sure you should not be passing the password to that query. Surely you shoudl be selecting on Email OR Mobile and then checking the password matches by doing a re-hash of the inputted password and compare against the hash on the DB. Not sure if nodejs has the equivalent of `password_verify()` in PHP

Comment: No no its just added to make tit bold.

Comment: @RiggsFolly couldn't understand your second point. Pls clearify

Comment: My point is hwo do you know the HASHED password without looking it up from the database?

Comment: the hash passsword is already inserted in database as string datatype. I am matching it with email or mobile number.

Comment: I used both || and OR, btw both allowd and working in phpMyadmin.

Comment: Try removing the ` symbols

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email = "' + email + '" || mobile = "' + email + '") AND password ="' + password + '"';

Comment: Make sure you wrap the values in ", not the column names

Comment: That's a bad idea to use concatenation in sql queries... You will be exposed to SQL injection...

Comment: I think node.js mysql automatically prevents sql injection? Not sure?

Comment: Only if you use prepared statements (?)